# wicd does not work on read-only file system

Tags: networking, filesystems, networkmanager, wicd

My root filesystem is mounted read-only.

I have installed `wicd`, but it fails to work with following error:

```
 IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/etc/wicd/manager-settings.conf'
```

It seems, every time I restart `wicd`, the configuration file is rewritten, but the content is the same.

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the location of the config files in `/usr/share/wicd/daemon/wicd-daemon.py`

So, if `/etc/wicd/` is readonly, move them to `/var/lib/wicd/`:

i.e.:

```
wireless_conf = "/var/lib/wicd/configurations/wireless-settings.conf"
wired_conf = "/var/lib/wicd/configurations/wired-settings.conf"

self.config = ConfigManager("/var/lib/wicd/configurations/manager-settings.conf")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do one of the following:

- Make `/etc/wicd/manager-settings.conf` a symlink to a file on a filesystem that is not read-only (whether this works or not will depend on the application logic) -- the advantage of this approach is that it only affects this single file;
- Bind mount `/etc/wicd` to a directory that is not on a read-only filesystem -- a disadvantage of this is that you have to do this on the granularity of a whole directory, but perhaps you can change the config file location so that this isn't an issue;
- Have a separate mount for /etc/wicd -- again, a disadvantage is that this is at the granularity of a directory.